# Accessing database records to populate dropdown list

Tags: database

Ive got a table that stores a model attribute for each record. Im populating a drop down list with all the models.

Is it possible to list each model type once? In other words I've got multiple records with a model attribute of radio. Im filling a drop down list with the model types from the table. Is there a way to only list it once? I.E. I have 5 records with a radio attribute, but when I fill the drop down list it only shows radio once?

Or do I have to create a new table with all model types and associate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly then try this:

suppose your Table structure is following:(STUDENT)

```
STUDENTID |  NAME | CLASS
001       |  ABC  | FY
002       |  PQR  | FY
003       |  LMN  | SY
004       |  XYZ  | SY
```

and you want unique Class to be populated in Combobox then you can write a following query:

```
select DISTINCT(CLASS) from STUDENT
```

which will give you following result:

```
CLASS
FY
SY
```

Comment: That works perfectly with the .uniq in rails. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use either `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT model
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY model
 ORDER BY model;
```

or `SELECT DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT model
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY model;
```

Both queries will return distinct values of model column.

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7113f/3)**